# Alternative charger for laptop

Tags: laptop, battery-life

I have a DELL chromebook 3100 2 in 1 and its 65W charger does not work anymore. I have purchased on-line a new one but, as it arrives, I have tried to charge it using a quick charger for Smartphones, with red USB (3.2), 33 W. It does work.

If I eventually do this, will I damage the battery? Or for some emergency situations no harm will actually be perceived?